# Function determining temperature of points along a curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $T=x^2+y^2+z^2$ be the function determining the temperature at the point $(x,y,z)$. Find a function that determines the temperature at the points along the curve $\vec\alpha(t)=(4\cos t, 4 \sin t, 16t)$.

I think that $\alpha$ describes an object moving in a circular manner upwards, as time increases, what I did was to set $x=4\cos t$, $y=4\sin t$, $z=16t$, square all three and add them so the equation looks like $T$ on one side, but I don't know if that's correct, what I've got:

$$\vec T=16\cos^2t+16\sin^2t+256t^2=16+256t^2$$

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Looks fine: you just need to use the parameterized forms of the coordinate functions in the way you did.  (Note: the parameter is "tracing out" a helix, if you want to visualize how the temperature function is behaving along the curve.)

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on that? Maybe I'm just tired but I don't understand what you mean, sorry.

Comment: Yes, you use the functions of $ \ t \ $ that you were given for each coordinate in the function of $ \ (x, \ y, \ z) \ $ .  You did this correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks okay, although you need to write $T$ not $\vec{T}$ as temperature is a scalar not a vector.

Comment: Perhaps the OP was seeking a way to indicate that temperature $T$ is now assigned to varying points, e.g. $T(t)$ as the parameterization varies the point along the spiral.